# Where to initialize random seed for use through multiple random modules?

Tags: c++, random, srand

So, every time I am developing something big, with multiple modules coming together to build a final functionality, I've been wondering the same question: Where to initialize the random seed if more than 1 module needs to use the random function?

If I have a certain class that needs random (e.g. class that initializes itself by sorting an input array with self-implemented quicksort, so I would need a random for the pivot choice), I usually have a private `static bool isRandOn;` variable, so before I start the random pivot choice, I check that variable and do `srand(time(NULL));` if the random is not on yet.

If I have a ton of utility functions in a namespace, I do a very similar thing: I put such a variable in an anonymous namespace inside my utils library, and do the more-or-less same thing as with a class.

*The problem I have* is when combining those modules. All by it self, I know each module will not set the seed more than once. But, I want to  be able to use a various amount of my modules together, I want other people to be able to use one or more of my modules independent of the others...

So, **what is the best way** to handle multiple random-seed-needing modules? Set the seed in each module? Do not set the seed at all but instead document the usage of random and make the user initialize the seed if he wants to use the module? Something third?

Comment: What's wrong with setting the seed more than once?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking :) Wouldn't it lower the random-ness of the whole thing together if the seed was effectively reset a few times throughout the execution process?

Comment: Assuming that you're using time(NULL) each time, and there's no way to really predict what time() is going to return, I don't see how one random would be measurably more random than the next.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking, is are you calling srand in the middle of your code somewhere, or do you have multiple classes that are just all calling it at the very beginning?  If you have 5 calls right at the start and then use the same seed the whole time It wouldn't really matter...

Comment: Since I've wondered this throughout multiple projects, some of which called seed at sporadic times during the runtime, some of which only at the beginning, I'm wondering for best practices over all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies as an answer: but if you wanted something simple, albeit hackish, just patch srand after the first call so subsequent calls will have no effect.  This is a no-library-required solution, and is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @penelope: it would probably (no expert). Also note that using the `time` function is not secure, the random numbers so generated can be used for amusing things (having balls pop on the screen at random places, etc...) but should not be used for secured things (like generating the hands of the players in an online poker games) as one could guess the random sequences in advance.

Comment: @Nowayz: instead of patching `srand`, one could write a wrapper :)

Comment: @Matthieu M.  That would rely more heavily on the method for generating the pseudo-random number rather than the seed.  I realize that it's possible, and has been demonstrated in attacks against the default php random generator, but this is not realistic in most scenarios.

Comment: Matthieu M. is right, creating a class wrapping srand would be a better solution.

Comment: @Nowayz patch srand? Don't mind (too) hackish solution... Even if I don't use them, I like to know them :D But I'm not sure what you are suggesting... could you maybe expand that in a more detailed answer?

Comment: @Matthieu M. I don't need it to be used for secure purposes, just have a bunch of algorithms that need pivot-like elements in the beginning usually.

Comment: @penelope Basically you could patch the bytecode of the first instructions of the srand function to pop the arg from the stack and then do a retn, thus bypassing the function.  I could post a detailed answer on how to logistically do this, but writing a class to wrap srand is really a far more clean solution.

Comment: @Nowayz Yes, you're right. Even if I hack my srand, there is no guarantee that anybody else will do that if they just take my module. And, there is already one wrapping answer down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Boost.Random rather than relying on some global state shared at the program level.

Boost.Random has two concepts:

- Engine: which generates random numbers
- Distributions: which adapt the result from the engines to provide results fitted to a certain distribution (normal, poisson, gaussian, ...)

Each module may then have its own Engine, or indeed several of them: there is no specific reason for a given Engine to be shared between several different functions within the same module.

As a final word: whatever you do make sure you have a way to set the seed(s) deterministically for bug repro purposes. Bug repro may benefit from having multiple engines (isolation of the parts helps).

Comment: I know about the deterministic seed for debugging. Learned that the hard way few years back :) This is a good suggestion, but since I'm looking for a best practice applicable in a wide variety of cases, any suggestions for when outside libraries like Boost are not allowed? (Or, at least, out-of-team libraries if developing in a team?)

Comment: @penelope: well, redevelopping the same concepts ? A mersenne twister is normally easily implemented, and you can use the results directly (it is similar to what `rand()` would generate). The distributions in Boost are just sugar coating to have more meaningful syntax than `rand() % 10 + 89` when you really want an integer in [89, 99). And of course, they do not introduce biais (contrary to my quick demo).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a special "module" for random number generation, and use that from the other parts of your application. Then you only seed once when the random-number module is initialized.

Comment: That only works if a) I'm the only one using and developing my application and b) nobody else will use any of my individual modules and c) it will not be mixed with anything from outside. I'm wondering what's the best practice that is as widely applicable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

@penelope gave a correct answer. There is some complex algorithm for generating pseudo-random number sequence behind `rand()`. This is like some function `rand_func(prev_rand)`, which generates next pseudo-random number from previous. For the first time you call `srand(time(NULL))`, which sets `prev_rand` to in these terms supposing `time(NULL)` to be quite undetermined. So you can safely call `srand()` (which sets ) multiple times.

The special issue is if you neet *predictable* pseudo-random sequences: for example, `srand(0)` etc. But it seems to be not your case.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I came with to avoid repeating always the same initial random sequence is to do the following in each module where you call the `random()` function:

```
/* Global variable to remember if we already initialized the PRNG */
static bool seed_initialized = false;

/* Helper function to avoid having always the same sequence again and again */
static void
prng_init (unsigned int seed)
{
  if (!seed_initialized)
    {
      srandom (seed);
      seed_initialized = true;
    }
}
```

And, each time you use `random()` in a function you start the function with something like:

```
 /* Initializing PRNG with a 'reasonably strong' random seed for our purpose */
 prng_init (time (NULL) - getpid());
```

This way, you ensure that:

1. You will initialize your PRNG at least the first time you go through;
2. You will never reinitialize the random sequence more than once within the module.

Hope this help!